# C++ controlling memory access and pointer dereferencing

Tags: c++, pointers, types

I am writing an API in C++ where I want to restrict what a programmer can do with pointers to objects the API creates.

For example,

```
// API
class object {
  // details unimportant
};

// Programmer's code
object o;               // OK
object *op = &o;        // OK
long *lp = (long *)op;  // No
object o2 = op[100];    // No
```

I understand that some of this is probably difficult or impossible given C++'s type system. Are there ways to enforce this kind of type usage pattern? Are there ways to restrict the available operations on a given pointer type? Would something like overloading `object`'s `operator&` work?

```
class object {
  object_pointer operator&();
};
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't. Why do you want to stop clients using pointers with your objects?

Comment: your requirement makes no sense to me

Comment: One possible approach is to use a sane language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way in C++ to prevent C-style casting of pointers.  Any (non-function) pointer may be C-style cast to any other pointer type.

And given a pointer, there is no way to tell the compiler "This is definitely not an array."  So you can't prevent `op[100]` either.

What you could do is hide all the members of the class itself, e.g. using the Pimpl idiom or C-style opaque structures/classes.  But this won't help you in terms of restricting users' abilities to obtain pointers to your instances and cast them.

C++ is a language for consenting adults.  If you don't consent, use another language.